# updateTrackingAreas using objective-c ... use of super and alloc

Tags: objective-c, mouseevent

I need to keep track of mouse movement locations. Ideally I wanted to use "setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents", which would be captured by the window or the subclassed NSView. But I was not sure where to put it. So instead, I will track mouse movements via updateTrackingAreas.

```
- (void) updateTrackingAreas {
    [self removeTrackingArea:trackingArea];
    trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:[self bounds]
        options:(NSTrackingActiveAlways | NSTrackingInVisibleRect | NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingMouseMoved)
        owner:self userInfo:nil];
    [self addTrackingArea:trackingArea];
    [super updateTrackingAreas];
}
```

My questions are these:

1. In the code, alloc is used.  Do I nee to free this?  If so, where would this be done?
2. At the end of the code, "super" is called.  I put it there because it is usually recommended to call the parent.  However, I am only tracking one area, so I am not sure if I need it. Can some please let me know if it is really needed or not?
3. Since setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents is not being used, do I need to use NSTrackingActiveWhenFirstResponder?  I does not seem that I do, but I may be wrong?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please post your code in the question.

Comment: - (void) updateTrackingAreas {
    [self removeTrackingArea:trackingArea];
    trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:[self bounds]
    options:(NSTrackingActiveAlways | NSTrackingInVisibleRect |
    NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | 
    NSTrackingMouseMoved)
    owner:self
    userInfo:nil];
        
   [self addTrackingArea:trackingArea];
        
   [super updateTrackingAreas];
}

Comment: The reason i put the code here and not in my question is because this program keeps complaining about my code being formatted wrong, and would not let me continue.  So I got desperate and took it out.  It is now above, but terribly formatted.  How can I and my code without it complaining about the formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If ARC ([Automatic Reference Counting](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW11)) is on, ARC will release `trackingArea`.
2. From the documentation of `updateTrackingAreas`:

> your implementation should call super.

3. From the documentation of `NSTrackingActiveWhenFirstResponder`

> The owner receives messages when the view is the first responder. This value specifies when the tracking area defined by an NSTrackingArea object is active.